# What happens if there are multiple beans having the same @Order value

Tags: java, spring, aop

I have two `@ControllerAdvice` classes. One is in the application level, the other one is in a dependency. Both @ControllerAdvice has @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE) annotation. **Which bean will be picked up (first) for creation?**

Controller advice inside application:

```
package com.package.one.errors

@ControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class ControllerAdvice1 {}
```

Controller advice from dependency:

```
package com.package.two.errors

@ControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class ControllerAdvice2 {}
```

The `ControllerAdvice1` is being used when I run the Spring Boot application. I suspect this has something to do with what beans are encountered first when scanning since the class with `@SpringBootApplication` is inside the same package as `ControllerAdvice1`. I would like to know the rules how Spring resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the API reference : [Ordered.getOrder()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/Ordered.html#getOrder--)

> Same order values will result in arbitrary sort positions for the
> affected objects

also

> The actual order can be interpreted as prioritization, with the first object (with the lowest order value) having the
> highest priority.

Comment: Leaving the link to the doc for OrderComparator class which is used to determine the order for @Order annotated beans:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/OrderComparator.html  . It's very clear: Objects that have the same order value will be sorted with arbitrary ordering with respect to other objects with the same order value.